Clarification about Szemeredi's theorem on arithmetic progressions
Szemerédi's theorem on arithmetic progressions states that if a sequence $\{a_n\} \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ has positive upper Banach density, i.e. if
$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \max_{m \geq 0} \frac{\#(\{a_n\} \ \cap \ [m+1, m+n])}{n} > 0,$$
then the sequence contains arbitrarily long finite arithmetic progressions.
This means that for every $k \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists some starting point $a \in \{a_n\}$ and some gap length $\Delta \in \mathbb{N}$ such that the $k$-term progression $$a, a + \Delta, a + 2\Delta, a + 3\Delta, \ldots, a+ k\Delta$$
is contained in $\{a_n\}$.
MY QUESTIONS. Can anything be said about what $\Delta$ are allowable? For example, could the following statement be true?
Question 1. If a sequence $\{a_n\} \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ has positive upper Banach density, then it contains arbitrarily long finite arithmetic progressions with gap length $1$.
These would be $k$ consecutive terms.
More generally, I could ask:
Question 2. For what proper subsets $\mathscr{D} \subset \mathbb{N}$ can we say that if a sequence $\{a_n\} \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ has positive upper Banach density, then it contains arbitrarily long finite arithmetic progressions with gap length $\Delta \in \mathscr{D}$?
A characterisation of all these sets $\mathscr{D}$ is probably too much to ask for, but are there any known examples? Question 1 is the extreme case $\mathscr{D} = \{1\}$. Maybe something of the form $\mathscr{D} = \{\text{even numbers}\}$ is known?

Take $a_n=2n$ to get a counterexample for Question 1.
The answer to Question 2 is affirmative. Given $\{a_n\}$ and $k$, Szemeredi gives you an arithmetic progression of length $2k$ with some difference $\Delta$. Take every second term of that progression to get a progression of even length (namely $2\Delta$) of length $k$.

Thanks! For Question 1, are there any examples that are not already (infinite) APs?

@approximate-identity Sure. For example $a_n=2^n$. Or $a_n=$ the $n$-th prime.

Sorry, I wasn't clear. Those sequences both have zero upper Banach density. I'm looking for a nonlinear sequence with positive upper Banach density that does not contain arbitrarily long APs with gap length 1.

@approximate-identity  Sorry; I forgot about the Banach density requirement. Consider the following "random AP". Take $a_0=0$ and define the later terms so that $a_{n+1}-a_n$ is always $2$ or $3$ but varies almost arbitrarily with $n$; for example, decide between $2$ and $3$ by flipping  a coin.  By "almost", I just mean to make sure you choose each of $2$ and $3$ infinitely often (so you don't end up with an AP from some stage on). The upper (and even the lower) Banach density is now $\geq1/3$ but there are no terms that differ by $1$.
